# Modifying MySQL table using BASH array

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a MySQL column which got incorrectly loaded with data.  I created a script which reads the text file of 14 million primary keys I know got messed up.  I have a basic bash `while` loop but instead of issuing a separate mysql command for every id, I'd like to do it for a set of id's (I do have 14 million after all).

currently:

```
while IFS='' read -r id || [[ -n "$id" ]]; do
    mysql -e "UPDATE my_table SET direct = 1 WHERE id = $id" -u $USER -p$PASS db
done < "$1"
```

what I would like to do is read in a set of id's and say something like `WHERE id in ($#ids)` without having to perform a bunch of loops and modulos.  Ideas?

Comment: doable, but bear in mind the normal command line and query string length limits. you'll only be able to stuff so many ids onto the cli before the shell will barf/truncate.

Comment: Query length limits?  I was thinking about building up a $STRING variable as I read in the file so $STRING looks like "1283792, 7657887263, 16876873", etc. then dumping that into the `in ()` clause.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` in mysql. any longer than that will be... not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ids in an array, and they don't contain commas, then you can join the values by `,` and formulate an IN-query like this:

```
mysql -e "UPDATE my_table SET direct = 1 WHERE id IN ($(IFS=,; echo "${ids[*]}"))" -u $USER -p$PASS db
```

This solves one part of your problem.

Another part is to split the 14 million ideas to workable chunks.
Something like this should work:

```
execute_update() {
    mysql -e "UPDATE my_table SET direct = 1 WHERE id IN $(IFS=,; echo "${ids[*]}")" -u $USER -p$PASS db
}

ids=()
while IFS='' read -r id; do
    ids+=($id)
    if [[ ${#ids[@]} = 200 ]]; then
        execute_update
        ids=()
    fi
done < "$1"

if [[ ${#ids[@]} < 200 ]]; then
    execute_update
    ids=()
fi
```

Comment: Oopsie, my bad, good you could figure it out, updated the post now in any case